# Calendar Intent field Title/Description not working in Motorola Xoom Honeycomb 3.1 and Acer Iconia

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing an app that send datas to Android calendar via Intent.
It works perfect with the default android calendar from 2.1 to 2.3.4 and also with 3rd party calendar like Jorte or Business Calender.

But with Honeycomb (Acer Iconia and Motorola Xoom) I am getting NO TITLE AND DESCRIPTION PASSED IN THE FIELD.

I have all the passed field filled, year, month, day, hours, minutes, but NO DESCRIPTION AND TITLE

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(pv.getYear()));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(pv.getMonth()));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(pv.getDay()));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(pv.getHours()));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(pv.getMinutes()));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 

intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(eventTime));
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
String description = pv.getDescription().trim();
intent.putExtra("title", title); // **NOT WORKING**
intent.putExtra("description", description); // **NOT WORKING**
startActivity(intent);
```

any idea?
Thanks
Sandro

EDIT:
Looks like there is no TITLE and DESCRIPTION on the Intent with Honeycomb.
The only way we are able to do that is using content provider, a totally different method.

Comment: Hi Sandro -- were you able to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try used its... 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-edit